How to deploy Node.js API which uses python scripts using spawn/child_process in vercel
I have completed the setup for Vercel in my Node.js project, but when I run the global link given by Vercel in the postman, it gives me an error saying

A server error has occurred
FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED

However it works fine when I run it locally even with the vercel dev command.
I have tried changing the vercel.json, but when I try running the vercel --prod it shows me this:

Due to builds existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings

I think the problem is that the Python runtime is not given by Vercel it assumes that I am just using Node.js and gives only the Node runtime. How can I make this work?
